# Finding the right battery?

Tags: lithium-ion, battery-operated

I have a 5v circuit that's running on a 3.7v 1000mAh battery. I got it changing just right and the circuit is running fine but it doesn't last as long as I want it too. So how can I find the right battery for my circuit to last longer?

Comment: Why not get one with a larger capacity?

Comment: How can I tell if a battery has larger capacity?

Comment: It will have a higher Ah amount, e.g. a 18650 Li-ion with 2200mAh.

Comment: They will either have a higher voltage at the same mAh rating or higher mAh rating for the same voltage.

Comment: Also, be careful of the Amp output rating of the battery and the Amps your circuit needs. If you are using a linear regulator, amps in = amps out. If you are using either a boost or buck converter, then power in = power out. You don't want a battery that can't provide enough power.

Comment: why are you running a 5V circuit on 3-4.2V (useful range of a LiPo single cell battery)? It would be better to use a 2-cell lipo (6-8.4V range) and linear (LDO) or DC-DC converter (Buck) to get the 5V no matter what the given input voltage is (within drop-out range of course, if you end up with a 2V dropout linear reg by accident)

Comment: Much more info needed. Is there a battery to 5V converter? What is your load and application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out approximately how long a battery will last in a circuit is simple if the current is known. For example, say you have a 3.7V to 5V converter and the load uses 1A.

1A @ 5V out = 1.35A @ 3.7V in**

If the load is constant then the battery is continuously discharging 1.35A.

1Ahr/1.35A = .741hrs or 44 minutes. Doubling the capacity to 2Ahr will lead to the battery lasting about 88 min.

**So to answer your question, figure out your load and time requirements and use those to calculate the battery capacity needed**

**In reality this will be higher depending on converter efficiency. If it was 90% then the battery would actually need to supply 1.5A. Additionally, as the battery discharges, it's voltage will slowly drop meaning even more current is required to power the same load. Finally, if the load current is changing with time you will need to perform an integral of the current waveform with respect to time to estimate battery life.